# Connect four checking for a win function only works in certain circumstances

Tags: python, python-3.x

My function for checking for a connect four win only works in the first rows but not any other row. Somewhere in my code the x and y got mixed up as well, is it my loop?

```
def check_win(it):
    #right diag - works
    for x in range (0, 6):
        for y in range (0, 5):
            if board[x][y] == it and board[x-1][y+1] == it and board[x-2][y+2] == it and board[x-3][y+3] == it:
                return True
    #left diag- works
    for x in range (0, 6):
        for y in range (0, 5):
            if board[x][y] == it and board[x-1][y-1] == it and board[x-2][y-2] == it and board[x-3][y-3] == it:
                return True
    #right- works
    for y in range(0, 6):
        if board[x][y] == it and board[x][y+1] == it and board[x][y+2] == it and board[x][y+3] == it:
            return True
    #down - works
    for y in range(0, 6):
         if board[x][y] == it and board[x-1][y] == it and board[x-2][y] == it and board[x-3][y] == it:
             return True
    return False
```

### For example here the code works, but only on the first row

```
    .  .  .  .  .  .  .
    .  .  .  .  .  .  .
    R  .  .  .  .  .  .
    R  .  .  .  .  .  .
    R  .  .  .  .  .  .
    B  B  B  B  .  .  .
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7
    Game Over!
    player 1  wins!
```

### When there is a connect four on any row above the first row as shown below, it doesn't work

```
    .  .  .  .  .  .  .
    B  .  .  .  .  .  .
    B  .  .  .  .  .  .
    B  .  .  .  .  .  .
    R  R  R  R  .  .  .
    B  R  B  R  B  .  .
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

Comment: The two `for y` loops don't have a nested `for x` loop. So they're just using the last `x` from the previous diagonal loop.

Comment: Also, in the left diag code, you access `board[x-1][y-1]`. That will get negative indexes when `x = 0` and `y = 0`.

Comment: And you have `board[x-1]` in the right diag code, too.

Comment: Wow I totally missed that, thank you